# Excluding Nodes RVest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am scraping blog text using RVest and am struggling to figure out a simple way to exclude specific nodes. The following pulls the text:

```
AllandSundry_test <- read_html
("http://www.sundrymourning.com/2017/03/03/lets-go-back-to-commenting-on-the-weather/")

testpost <- AllandSundry_test %>% 
html_node("#contentmiddle") %>%
html_text() %>%
as.character()
```

I want to exclude the two nodes with ID's "contenttitle" and "commentblock". Below, I try excluding just the comments using the tag "commentblock".

```
 testpost <- AllandSundry_test %>% 
   html_node("#contentmiddle") %>%
   html_node(":not(#commentblock)")
   html_text() %>%
   as.character()
```

When I run this, the result is simply the date -- all the rest of the text is gone. Any suggestions?

I have spent a lot of time searching for an answer, but I am new to R (and html), so I appreciate your patience if this is something obvious.

Comment: Can you please provide the url from which you wanted to scrape? I just couldn't understand the gist of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I edited the question with the exact example I am using. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there. You should use `html_nodes` instead of `html_node`.

`html_node` retrieves the first element it encounter, while `html_nodes` returns each matching element in the page as a list.
The `toString()` function collapse the list of strings into one.

```r
library(rvest)

AllandSundry_test <- read_html("http://www.sundrymourning.com/2017/03/03/lets-go-back-to-commenting-on-the-weather/")

testpost <- AllandSundry_test %>% 
  html_nodes("#contentmiddle>:not(#commentblock)") %>% 
  html_text %>%
  as.character %>%
  toString

testpost
#> [1] "\n\t\tMar\n\t\t3\n\t, Mar, 3, \n\t\tLet's go back to 
#> commenting on the weather\n\t\t\n\t\t, Let's go back to commenting on 
#> the weather, Let's go back to commenting on the weather, I have just 
#> returned from the grocery store, and I need to get something off my chest. 
#> When did "Got any big plans for the rest of the day?" become 
#> the default small ...<truncated>
```

You still need to clean up the string a bit.

Comment: So for some reason, it still seems to be picking up comments. Thanks, the html on this particular website seems messy.

Comment: You are right, I was so sure I didn't really check. I'm now not sure why this does not work. Anyway, editing the answer with a working solution.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly looks like GGamba solved it for you- however, in my machine, I had to remove the > after `#contentmiddle`. Therefore, this section was instead:

```
html_nodes("#contentmiddle:not(#commentblock)")
```

Best of luck!
Jesse