# How to exclude tags from scraping with rvest

Tags: r, rvest

I have following html excerpt:

```
<div class="price">
  <span class="float-right"><strong>1900</strong> USD</span>
</div>
```

I would like to retrieve the amount and the currency as two seprate variables.

For the amount, I can get it without any problem with the following piece of code:

```
price <- rentalagency_html %>%
  rvest::html_nodes(css="div.price > span.float-right > strong") %>%
  rvest::html_text(trim=TRUE)
price
```

For the currency, how can I get only "USD" without the amount? Basically, I want to exclude the  tag.

Comment: is there an url you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read in the entire 'span' node, you could then split the resultant text into two by space?

```
x <- '<div class="price">
  <span class="float-right"><strong>1900</strong> USD</span>
</div>'

x %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes(css='div.price > span') %>% 
  html_text(trim=TRUE) %>% 
  strsplit(' ')
[[1]]
[1] "1900" "USD"
```

Comment: Thanks. It works as long as you have the price and the currency. Unfortunately it can happen that there is no price. I would be nice if we could exclude the value inside the tag strong when doing html_nodes. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you give example html with no price?

Comment: Here is an example:  <div class="price">
         
         <span class="float-right"><strong>Price on request</strong> NA</span>
        </div>

Comment: Or try the :not() syntax to exclude ‘strong’. I’m not at a machine so can’t try, but see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43038101/excluding-nodes-rvest

Comment: I actually tried it before posting my question. I couldn't get it to work. I probably have an issue with the syntax: currency <- rentalagency_html %>%
  rvest::html_nodes(css="div.price > span.float-right:not(strong)") %>%
  rvest::html_text(trim=TRUE)
currency

Comment: Here's another attempt, with xpath. Ugly, though, and the output will need some further stripping of empty strings: `x %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes('div.price>span.float-right') %>% html_nodes(xpath='//*[not(name()="strong")]/text()') %>% html_text(trim=TRUE)`

Comment: Hmm. With your price on request html string, my output with above script (including xpath) is: `[1] ""  "NA"  ""` I'm using `rvest_0.3.4`, `xml2_1.2.2`. and `R 3.6.1.`

Comment: I finally managed to get it to work:   currency = rentalagency_html %>%
    rvest::html_nodes(xpath = paste("//*[contains(@class, 'price')]//span/",
    "node()[not(self::strong)]",
    sep = "")) %>%
    rvest::html_text(trim=TRUE)